# How to get command line bigquery output from java

Tags: java, command-line, google-bigquery

Query

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_name = 'shakespeare'
```

When I from command line output looks formatted

```
+-------------+-----------+
| column_name | data_type |
+-------------+-----------+
| word        | STRING    |
| word_count  | INT64     |
| corpus      | STRING    |
| corpus_date | INT64     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

When I run from java, get a json response.
Is there any way to print command line look a like output using java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without doing some parsing/formatting yourself. What you are seeing in this example is the BigQuery CLI tool formatting the JSON response from the API (it will always return JSON) using Python under the hood. You'd need to do the same in your Java application. There might be libs that do this already, so have a look around.